# String objects count SCJP

Tags: java, string

Another exam question that makes me confused:

```
public String makinStrings() {
 String s = “Fred”;
 s = s + “47”;
 s = s.substring(2, 5);
 s = s.toUpperCase();
 return s.toString();
}
```

the question is:
"How many String objects will be created when this method is invoked?"

correct answer is supposed to be 3 but I counted more:
Fred
47
Fred47
ed4
ED4

is 3 really the correct answer? If so - why?

Answer (score 1):

String constants are instantiated at the moment the class is instantiated. Because of that, the strings "Fred" and "47" are instantiated before the method is invoked, and not during method invocation.

This article explains it : [The String Constant Pool](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/)

But I will refine it a little more: the Java Virtual Machine Specification specifies that the constants "Fred" and "47" be placed as entries in the String Constant Pool. ( [java SE specs, loading and linking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1) ).

This happens *when the class is loaded*.

Another point to focus here: the question is how many objects are *instantiated*.

So,

**String s = "Fred"** : doesn't instantiate a new String object, only uses a reference from the internalized "Fred" constant.

**s = s + "47"** : the '+' operator implies a concatenation operation; the result of that concatenation is a new String object. So, 1 String instantiated. The "47" was loaded with the Class...

**s = s.substring(2,5):** the method definition specifies that a new string object must be returned ( [String.substring javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) ), so, 2 Strings instantiated.

Even if the implementation ( this, for example [the openJDK java.lang.String implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)) may use some kind of constructor to only refer to a portion of the character array that have the String internal value, the result *is* a new String, even if a kind of "lazy" one.

**s = s.toUpperCase()**: same here, the toUpperCase method must return a new String. So, 3 Strings instantiated.

And finally, **s.toString()** returns a representation of the object as a String. Since a String *is* already a String, s.toString() returns only the exact same String object...

Comment: From Java Language Specification [Constant Pool  has been moved to Java Heap since Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#jdk7changes) , and previously  the pool was in `permgen space` on hotspot JVM .

Comment: this doesn't exclude the fact that string constants are not instantiated during method invocation, but when the class is instantiated, does it?

Comment: Nopes it doesn't exclude but the comment is on your previous version of answer where cache memory concept was mentioned ......

Answer (score 0):

3 objects: 
Fred 
Fred47 
ED4

```
 s = s + “47”;
```

47 won't be created on the String pool

```
s = s.substring(2, 5);
```

Shouldn't create a separate string but will follow flyweight pattern and internally point to the same string.

Comment: Why 47 won't be created in String Pool , and if not then where it will be created ? and `s.substring(2,5)` will definately gonna create new String `Object in heap memory`